# find and copy exec command not recursive

Tags: ubuntu, find, recursive

I'm running this command to **find all the files** named **deploy.php** in my whole project and make a copy of them and place them in the same directory as they were found, with name **deploy_bkp.php**

```
find . -type f -name "deploy.php" -exec cp  {} deploy_bkp.php  \;
```

But it's not working recursively, it's only working for files on the top directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://askubuntu.com/questions/497122/find-and-exec-in-found-folder you should use `-execdir` 
Your command should look like this:

```
find . -type f -name "deploy.php" -execdir cp  {} deploy_bkp.php  \;
```